# Sample all elements from a set at least once, with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, coupon-collector

I've seen the Coupon collector's problem and I believe this is a variant of it but I can't quite wrap my head around it. This is not a homework assignment.

I have a set of *k* elements. I randomly sample *s* elements from the set and then replace them. If I do this *n* times, what is the probability that I will have sampled every single element at least once?

Comment: Consider using inclusion-exclusion on the events "I did not find the $i$'th element in any of the attempts."

Comment: Is your sample of $s$ elements without replacement? I.e. are they guaranteed to be distinct?

Comment: Good question. Yes, the sample is without replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't yet have the solution in closed form, but I'll leave this here as it gives a computable expression for this probability, and perhaps can be used to find a more ideal solution.

Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$th element of the $k$ is never sampled in the course of this process. We wish to compute $P((\bigcup A_i)^c) = 1 - P(\bigcup A_i)$. This quantity can be written, by the principle of [inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability), as
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i} \sum_{J\subset [1,\ldots,k], \lvert J\rvert = i} P(A_J),
$$
where $A_J = \bigcap_{j\in J} A_j$. First we need to compute the $P(A_J)$. This is the probability that a fixed set $J$ of the elements is never sampled throughout the process. This happens in one trial with probability $\frac{\binom{ k-\lvert J\rvert}{s}}{\binom{k}{s} }$. The trials are independent, so the probability that it happens in all trials is the $n$th power of this. Substituting into the above expression, the result is given by
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{k}{s}^n }
\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i} \sum_{J\subset [1,\ldots,k], \lvert J\rvert = i} 
\binom{ k-\lvert J\rvert}{s}^n
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{\binom{k}{s}^n }
\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i} \binom{k}{i} 
\binom{ k-i}{s}^n
$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375470.