# Probability of seeing n cards after r rounds of drawing k cards with replacement.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector

Suppose I have a deck of $n$ cards. I draw $k$ cards from the deck and note down which cards I have seen. I then replace the cards that I drew and shuffle the deck. I repeat the process of drawing $k$ cards from the deck for a total of $r$ times.

What is the probability after $r$ rounds that I have seen every card in the deck of $n$ cards.

I was able to simulate this for $n=52$, $k=34$, and $r=9$ using a Monte Carlo simulation in Python and got $\approx .995$. I am hoping that this is generalizable and that there is a way to directly calculate the probability. I know that the denominator would be $(_nC_k)^r$ but the numerator is proving difficult to calculate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i \binom ni \left(\frac{\binom{n-i}{k}}{\binom nk}\right)^r
$$
You can prove this with the principle of inclusion exclusion. Start with $1$, and then for each card, subtract out the probability that the card was not chosen. There are $n$ cards, so we subtract $n\cdot \left[\binom{n-1}k/\binom nk\right]^r$. However, events where two cards were not chosen have now been subtracted twice, so these need to be added back in, meaning we add in $\binom n2 \left[\binom{n-2}k/\binom nk\right]^r$. Continuing this pattern of corrections leads to the stated formula.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1836308/177399), joriki used this calculation as an intermediate step in determining the expected number of drawings it takes to see all cards, when you draw $k$ each time, giving a generalization of the coupon collector's problem.

Comment: You beat me to it! By the way, I think you only need to sum for $ i \leq n - k $.